# Video autoplay and loop everywhere (responsive)

Tags: javascript, mobile, video, responsive-design, html5-video

I want to have a video to auto play in loop as background every where (the video as no sound).

It works like this however when I arrive to the smartphone the video doesn't start at all

```
<video id="video" autoplay loop>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

is there some JS or jQuery like this

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('onLoad',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```

I just want the video to load no matter where (it is a small video so the bandwidth is not a question)

Comment: take a look at this plugin - http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to put on mobile a back up poster of the video as a gif and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code javascript

```
<script>
function playvideo()
{
document.getElementById("video").play();
}

myVid=document.getElementById("video");
myVid.oncanplay=playvideo();
</script>
```

Hope this help!